# Python Websocket Asyncio - class and initialisation issues

Tags: python, class, websocket, python-asyncio, pymodbus

I try to make a websocket asynchronous server in python and it would not run.

here is the error traceback.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "websocketserver5_asyncio.py", line 412, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "websocketserver5_asyncio.py", line 389, in main
    async with websockets.serve('', '192.168.0.24', PORTNUM, partial(Websocket(), client)):
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'client' and 'handler'
```

I don't understand exactly what the problem is here, even though the traceback shows the error, I can't figure it out what is to do.

class Websocket():

```
def __init__(self, client, handler): #, server, sock, address
    try:
        super(Websocket, self).__init__()

        self.modbus = client
        self.functions = {
            "relais1": partial(self.simple_switch, COILBASE + 16),
            "relais2": partial(self.simple_switch, COILBASE + 1),
            "relais3": partial(self.simple_switch, COILBASE + 2),
            "set_temp1": partial(self.set_temperature1, 524),
            "temperatur1": partial(self.read_temperature, 2),
            "temperatur2": partial(self.read_temperature, 3),
            "heizen1": partial(self.heating, 524),
            "heizen2": partial(self.heating, 525),
            "heatread": partial(self.simple_read, 524),
            "systemp": self.systemp
        }
    except Exception as exception:
        logger.exception("constructor")
        raise

def __await__(self, client):
    return self._async_init().__await__()

async def _async_init(self, client):
    self._conn = connect("wss://echo.websocket.org")
    self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()
    return self    


enter async def main():
logging.basicConfig()

with ModbusClient(host=HOST, port=PORT) as client:
    client.connect()
    time.sleep(0.025)

    print("Websocket server on port %s" % PORTNUM)

    async with websockets.serve('', '192.168.0.24', PORTNUM, partial(Websocket(), client)):
```

here is the complete code witch I posted few days agor.

```
import asyncio
import json
import os
import secrets
import signal
import websockets
from websockets import connect

import sys
import shutil
import logging
import time
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import functools
from functools import partial
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


UNIT = 0x1

HOST = '192.168.0.24'

PORT = 5020

COILBASE = 512


PORTNUM = 8001


class Websocket():

    def __init__(self, client, handler): 
        try:
            super(Websocket, self).__init__()

            self.modbus = client
            self.functions = {
                "relais1": partial(self.simple_switch, COILBASE + 16),
                "relais2": partial(self.simple_switch, COILBASE + 1),
                "relais3": partial(self.simple_switch, COILBASE + 2),
                "set_temp1": partial(self.set_temperature1, 524),
                "temperatur1": partial(self.read_temperature, 2),
                "temperatur2": partial(self.read_temperature, 3),
                "heizen1": partial(self.heating, 524),
                "heizen2": partial(self.heating, 525),
                "heatread": partial(self.simple_read, 524),
                "systemp": self.systemp
            }
        except Exception as exception:
            logger.exception("constructor")
            raise

    def __await__(self, client):
        
        return self._async_init().__await__()

    async def _async_init(self, client):
        self._conn = connect("wss://echo.websocket.org")
        self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()
        return self


    def simple_switch(self, address, value):
        """ value can be one of "on", "off" or "get" """
        if value in ['on', 'off']:
            rq = self.modbus.write_coil(address, value == 'on', unit=UNIT)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            print("rq = self.modbus.write_coil(address, value == on, unit=UNIT)")
        elif value != 'get':
            raise ValueError(value)
        
        rp = self.modbus.read_coils(address, unit=UNIT)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        return "on" if rp.bits[0] else "off"


    async def set_temperature1(self, address, value):
        print("set_temperature1 was triggerd")

        
        print("database_reading")
        print(self.database_reading()[1][0])
        
        if (self.database_reading()[0][1]) == 524 and (self.database_reading()[1][1]) == 'on':
            print("DB-Reading from set_temperature1 'heizen1': ", self.database_reading()[1][1])

            while True:

                print("Loop!!!!!!!")

                rp = self.modbus.read_coils(address, unit=UNIT)
                print(rp.bits[0])
                time.sleep(0.01)

                if rp.bits[0] == False:
                    rq = self.modbus.write_coil(address, value == "on", unit=UNIT)
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    print("Heating is active!!!!")

                print(address)
                time.sleep(0.01)

                print(type(self.read_temperature( address == 2, 'get')))
                print(type(value))

                if float(self.read_temperature( address == 2, 'get')) >= float(value):
                    print("Heating is on!!!!!!!")
                    time.sleep(0.01)

                    print(address)
                    rq = self.modbus.write_coil(address, value == "off", unit=UNIT)
                    time.sleep(0.01)

                    print("Heating Temperture is achieved! -> deactivate heating")

                if (self.database_reading()[0][1]) == 524 and (self.database_reading()[1][1]) == 'off':
                    break
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                


    def database_reading(self):

        def dict_factory(cursor, row):
            d = {}
            for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
                d[col[0]] = row[idx]
            return d

        
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect("state")
        sqliteConnection.row_factory = dict_factory
        zeiger = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        zeiger.execute("SELECT * FROM heating_relais_state")

        row =  zeiger.fetchone()
        rowDict = dict(zip([c[0] for c in zeiger.description], row))


        print(type(row))

        print("row1")


        result = row.items()
        row1 = list(result)
        print(row1)
        

        print(row1[1][1])

        sqliteConnection.commit()

        if sqliteConnection:
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")


    def simple_read(self, address, value):
        try:
            if value != 'get':
                raise ValueError(value)

            rp = self.modbus.read_coils(address, unit=UNIT)
            time.sleep(0.01)

            def dict_factory(cursor, row):
                d = {}
                for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
                    d[col[0]] = row[idx]
                return d

            sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect("state")
            sqliteConnection.row_factory = dict_factory
            zeiger = sqliteConnection.cursor()
            zeiger.execute("SELECT * FROM heating_relais_state")

            row =  zeiger.fetchone()
            rowDict = dict(zip([c[0] for c in zeiger.description], row))
            print("row12")
            print(row)
            self.sendMessage(json.dumps(row))
            
            row =  zeiger.fetchone()
            self.sendMessage(json.dumps(row))

            sqliteConnection.commit()

            if sqliteConnection:
                sqliteConnection.close()
                print("The SQLite connection is closed")

            time.sleep(0.01)
            return "on" if rp.bits[0] else "off"
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def read_temperature(self, address, value):
        if value != "get":
            raise ValueError(value)
        response = self.modbus.read_holding_registers(0x00, 8, unit=UNIT)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        t = response.registers[address]
        time.sleep(0.01)
        z = t/10

        return z

mean Relaise_State = True | this depends on the temperature
            sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect("state")
            zeiger = sqliteConnection.cursor()

            sql_anweisung = ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS heating_relais_state (
            heating_relais_address INTEGER, 
            state TEXT)""")

            zeiger.execute(sql_anweisung)


            zeiger.execute("SELECT * FROM heating_relais_state")
            inhalt = zeiger.fetchall()
            for inhalt in inhalt:
                print(inhalt)

            sqliteConnection.commit()

            if sqliteConnection:
                sqliteConnection.close()
                print("The SQLite connection is closed")


        elif value != 'get':
            raise ValueError(value)

        rp = self.modbus.read_coils(address, unit=UNIT)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        return "on" if rp.bits[0] else "off"


    def systemp(self, value):

        res = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline()
        temp = (res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))
        time.sleep(0.01)
        return temp



    async def receive(self):
        try:
            message = await self.websocket.recv()

            commands = json.loads(message)
            new_state = {}

            print("Echoing '%s'" % commands)

            for key, value in commands.items():
                function = self.functions[key]
                print("function '%s'" % function)
                new_state[key] = function(value)
                print("new_state '%s'" % new_state)
                print("key '%s'" % key)
                print("value '%s'" % value)
            print(json.dumps(new_state))
            await self.websocket.send(json.dumps(new_state))

            print("Echoing '%s'" % commands)


        except Exception as exception:
            logger.exception("handle message")
            raise

        return await self.websocket.recv()


    async def sendMessage(self, message):
        await self.websocket.send(message)

    async def close(self):
        await self._conn.__aexit__(*sys.exc_info())

    async def handler(self, websocket):
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            print(message)


async def main():
    logging.basicConfig()


    with ModbusClient(host=HOST, port=PORT) as client:
        client.connect()
        time.sleep(0.025)

        print("Websocket server on port %s" % PORTNUM)


        async with websockets.serve('', '192.168.0.24', PORTNUM, partial(Websocket(), client)):
```

I am trying to migrate my old websocket server to the sockets module, unfortunately without success. I have no experience with the sockets module. I also have little experience with object-oriented programming.

A minimal example of how to create a non-blocking websocket server would help me.

It is important that the module pymodbus is integrated, because the websocket server acts as a modbus client to take over the hardware control. I use javascript as the frontend.

If anyone has a better idea or an example of how to make such a project more professional, i would be happy to receive suggestions.

Why I am trying to migrate the former script SimpleWebSocketServer to websockets was that I wanted to integrate a while loop under set temperature and this loop blocked the whole script. Unfortunately, there are only a few good manuals on the net on this topic, let along with a modbus implementation.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. You are giving us a huge code dump and not even showing us where there error is. The traceback has the error, the failing line and the calls that got the code to the failure.

Comment: Well, the Websocket constructor takes one argument, client, and the failing line of code tries to call it without an argument.  The traceback makes that clear.  Do you have a question about that?

Comment: echo = await Websocket() has been removed, the error is gone. However, I get another one `TypeError: argument of type 'functools.partial' is not iterable
`

Comment: I can do nothing better than to quote tdelaney from yesterday: "You are giving us a huge code dump and not even showing us where there error is. The traceback has the error, the failing line and the calls that got the code to the failure."  Please notice how easy it was to fix the previous problem when you looked at the traceback.  If you want to fix bugs in Python you must study the traceback, otherwise you will waste hours looking in the wrong place.  Also, if you removed a line of code please edit your question - otherwise we don't even know what program you are trying to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm not an expert and don't know stackoverflow very well, or have any experience in how to ask a software development question properly. I have now simplified the code a bit. I'm just trying to get the program to run, unfortunately I can't do anything with the traceback, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. I think there is something fundamentally wrong with my code, as I said, I am not a software engineer.

Comment: I have now edited my question, I hope it is now a little more understandable, I point out once again that I am not an expert in programming, and hope for some indulgence. please take a look at my code and tell me what I would have to change. thank you very much for the help.